# Global taxi service with child seats

Tags: transportation, children, taxis, child-safety-seats

Is there some global taxi service or other solution that enables requesting cars with child seats when traveling in a new country? Preferably through a mobile application like Uber.

Using taxi in a new country is easy with Uber, because the app is the same everywhere around the world. However, Uber does not seem to provide a child car seat option in most locations. There are the occasional local taxi operators with their own mobile applications that provide child seat options. But I'm not interested in downloading a new app and signing up for a new service for every new trip I make, so I'm looking for some global service, or at least one with as much coverage as possible.

Answer (score 5):

**No**, there isn't. Taxis tend to be *very* regional and a few countries have even a nationwide service, never mind an international one.

Uber does have a "request car seat" option in a select few cities, but this is nowhere near global. (At time of writing, I believe it's limited to a few large US cities.)

https://help.uber.com/h/3abcbae1-132b-42a9-8277-0dab00fa3879